# Subscriptions / Filters based on searches

Tags: feature-request, search, email, tag-filters

I would like to set up a subscription / filter that sends me an email whenever a new post matches that search.  I can do this with searches that use tags, but not with searches that are based on the text in the post.

I suggest either

- Better Documenting how to do this (I can't find it),
- Implementing this feature.

Comment: You can have tag sets sending you emails, but it only lets you define tags, not precise searches.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Sorry to hear this has not been implemented.